# file upload not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, file-upload

I have in my asp.net page

```
       <input id="MyTextBox" runat="server" type="text" name="T1" size="20"/>

       <asp:Button ID="UploadFileButton" runat="server" Text="Upload"  /> 

      <input id="FileUpload" runat="server"  type="file"  style="height: 22px; visibility:hidden;" />
```

linked to JS script:

```
       $("#UploadFileButton").live("click", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            $("#FileUpload").click();

       });
     $(function() {
       $('#FileUpload').change(function() {
               $("#MyTextBox").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

This means when the user click `UploadFileButton` ,the chose file select popup shows.
After the user chose a file the MyTextBox=Selct file path.

My problem is that my script works in Chrome but not in Firefox.
Any ideas please if someone has already encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you research this you find that in a lot of browsers triggering a click on the `<input type='file' />` element is not allowed. It works in Chrome as long as the click is triggered by *actual* human interaction - even if the click event handler of another element triggers the click event on another. I'm only 90% sure about this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can use this code:

```
<input id="FileUpload" runat="server"  type="file"  style="height: 22px; onchange="fill();"/>

    <script language="javascript">
    function fill()
    {    
      $("#<%=MyTextBox.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=FileUpload.ClientID%>").val())
    }
    </script>
```